# How can i create controller in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.1

Hi  I want to create **controller** but  i tired because of command show **could not open input file php:artisian** what's the problem's can you help me.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you installed Laravel on the right way, https://laravel.com/docs/5.3

One you set your project up it's possible to call the artisan command. Make sure you cd into you project folder and see all the default Laravel files (/app,/bootstrap,.env,artisan etc...).

To create the controller you need to run the following command in terminal/cmd: `php artisan make:controller MyController`. This will create MyController for you.

One you want to setup a development php server you can run: `php artisan serve`. This will run a development server on your local computer.

If you still have any problems, please let us know!

Hope this works!